# Within cellForRowAtIndexPath getting height of cell when cells are variable height

Tags: iphone, ios

I create custom cells within my tableview some have images and are tall some are just text.  The height of the cells are calculated in heightForRowAtIndexPath, which I beleive is done before cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  I want to place an imageview at the bottom of the cell regardless of heigh, but I am not sure how to get the calculated height from within cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: `CGFloat height = [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the delegate, but you'll be asking twice since the tableView already asks and sizes the cell accordingly.  It's better to find out from the cell itself...

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, deque or create UITableViewCell *cell
// this makes the call to heightForRow... and sizes the cell
CGFloat cellHeight = cell.contentView.bounds.size.height;

// alter the imageView y position (assuming the rest of the frame is correct)
CGRect imageFrame = myImageView.frame;
imageFrame.y = cellHeight - imageFrame.size.height;   // place the bottom edge against the cell bottom
myImageView.frame = imageFrame;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the height returned from cell.contentView.bounds.size.height is different from the height calculated in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Mark, did you get a solution to this? cell.contentView seems to be returning the cell's original height and width.

Answer (score 15):

Too late for an answer..

But, like @user216661 pointed out, the problem with taking the height of the Cell or the ContentView is that it returns the cells original height. Incase of rows with Variable height, this is an issue.

A better solution is to get the Rect of the Cell (`rectForRowAtIndexPath`) and then get the Height from it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    UITableViewCell *aCell = (UITableViewCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aCellIdentifier];
    if (aCell == nil) {
        CGFloat aHeight = [iTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath].size.height;
        // Use Height as per your requirement.
    }

    return aCell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are allowed to call heightForRowAtIndexPath yourself!  Just pass the indexPath from cellForRowAtIndexPath as an argument and you can know the height of the cell you are setting up.

Assuming you are using a UITableViewController, just use this inside cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
float height = [self heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```